# Did Tianzhou-2 have a TLE before docking with Tianhe 8 hours after launch? Which is the 2nd stage rocket body and roughly how soon will it reenter?

Tags: space-station, tracking, two-line-elements, tiangong-space-station

Clicking on https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/stations.txt I get

```
2021-046B               
1 48804U 21046B   21149.88975173 -.00002388  75553-5  00000+0 0  9993
2 48804  41.4722  34.7864 0094547 179.0161 181.0974 16.05672466    50

2021-046C               
1 48805U 21046C   21149.89779632  .01450276  67423-5  18073-2 0  9999
2 48805  41.1261  34.9613 0236852 161.1625 199.8157 15.70749610    62

2021-046D               
1 48806U 21046D   21149.77945376 -.00002245  71127-5  00000+0 0  9990
2 48806  41.3640  35.6970 0231374 151.6339 263.0992 15.75049590    44

2021-046E               
1 48807U 21046E   21149.89767626 -.00002275  72078-5  00000+0 0  9993
2 48807  41.8096  34.6730 0232555 177.8263 182.6548 15.69878843    65
```

and presumably one of those may be the 2nd stage body that *will or won't fall back to Earth soon in a controlled or uncontrolled way.*

But there's no `2021-046A` currently, and according to Space News' [Tianzhou-2 docks with China’s space station module... Tianhe (which) paves way for June crewed mission.](https://spacenews.com/tianzhou-2-docks-with-chinas-space-station-module/) it docked with Tianhe (`2021-035A`, `48274`) about 8 hours after launch.

**Question(s):**

1. Did Tianzhou-2 have a TLE before docking with Tianhe 8 hours after launch?
2. What object is the 2nd stage rocket body and roughly how soon will it reenter?